# What is p180 in ruby version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When i type ruby -v in my console, it returns ruby 1.9.2p180, i am just wondering what this p180 means?

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: I guess it's patch. On the way for a future release.

Answer (score 14):

It's the patch level. Patch levels increase when they make a new build of an existing release that fixes known bugs.